# Jdeveloper Weblogic: How to get the deployed image path

Tags: xslt, path, xsl-fo, jdeveloper

I'm setting up a web application that should generate the pdf of the selected row from a table. The pdf has a background image ($image.png) that is located in a different folder from the XSL file ($template).

The managed bean get's the template and with a XML generate a PDF.

Path:

bean (ViewController\Application Sources\view\bean)

$image (ViewController\Web Content\resources\background)

$template (ViewController\Web Content\resources\stylesheet)

The only way i was able to get the image was using the absolute path (file:\\C:\some\folder\image.png).

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm">

        <fo:region-body background-image="file:\\\background/image.png"/>

    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

I'm trying to get the relative project path when the project is launched with the Weblogic.

Comment: Can you pass (the absolute path of) the `$image` value to your XSLT as a parameter?  See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/58389757/4092205.

Comment: I would if I could, I'm working to a project that as to go to another server which I do not have control over. So the only reasonable solution that i thought is to give it the relative Path.

Comment: Using the relative path should work.  It should be relative to the FO file.  You may instead be able to set an `xml:base` attribute (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/) in the FO file to force the formatter to evaluate the `background-image` property relative to a known location irrespective of the location of the XSL-FO file.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I'm trying to find the XSL-FO file path. Since the hole operation is done via FOP library, I'm trying to find the temporary location of the xsl-fo file.

Comment: Check the code you use to call the formatter, it may have optional parameter to set the System ID or base path for relative references

Comment: Sorry for the deelay. At the moment i'm able to call the image by the absolute path. Can't get programmatically the path. I'll search a way to get the relative path. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the file starts from the context-root, to get that I deployed the project in the local weblogic, and from the console, I got the context-root.

I'm still not sure of the currect path for my problem, but for the moment i was able to display the image using:

```
<fo:region-body background-image="url('http://127.0.0.1:7101/context- 
root/path/to/img/image.png')"/>
```

Note:
I now use the 'url' tag instead of 'file:///' tag.

The next step is to get the relative path.

I'd like to thank every one who tried to answer my question.